# Is it pleonastic to say "Il ne suffit que de ..." instead of "Il suffit de ..."?

Tags: grammaire

> Il **ne** suffit **que** de peu pour rendre un animal dépressif.
>
> {instead of}: Il suffit de peu pour rendre un animal dépressif.

While inserting "ne ... que" into the "il suffit de ..." construction stands to logic at least, I've never heard French speakers say it. Is it a case of pleonasm to be avoided, or does it actually serve as an intensifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Il ne suffit que de peu...*

might be heard and indeed serves as a pleonastic intensifier.

The sentence style is getting a little heavy in the process though, as compared to that of the simpler form.

*Peu* might be considered slightly formal so one might have heard instead:

> *Il suffit de peu de chose pour rendre un animal dépressif.*
>
> *Il suffit de pas grand chose pour...*
>
> *Il suffit d'un rien pour...*
>
> *Un rien suffit à rendre un animal dépressif*

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you personally use the “Il ne suffit que de …” construction?

Comment: I don't think I would.

Comment: @user17522 Yes, the fact it convey the same meaning is already well known by the OP and stated in my reply. A pleonasm is not necessarily "not right", it is a figure of speech than has some use cases.